# Splitting the Tangent Bundle of a Vector Bundle along the Zero Section

Tags: differential-geometry, algebraic-topology

Good evening everyone, I have a small question:

Assume we have a vector bundle $E = \bigcup\limits_{x\in M} E_x$ over a manifold $M$. I now want to show the following well-known equation: $$TE_M \cong TM \oplus E$$

I've seen it done with short exact sequences, but I wonder if it can be done more elementary: Let $s : M \hookrightarrow E$ be the zero section (i.e. $s(x) = 0 \in E_x$), then we get for each $x\in M$ the direct sum $E_x = \{0\} \oplus E_x = s(x) \oplus E_x$, so:
$$E= s(M) \oplus E$$

For the tangent bundle, this means (identifying $x = s(x)$) $$T_{x}E = T_{x}s(M) \oplus T_{x}E \cong T_xM \oplus E_x,$$ since $s(M) \cong M$ and $T_xE = T_x E_x \cong E_x$ as it is a vector space.

So, my question is: Does anyone see a mistake or something essential missing from my "proof"?

Comment: I may be mistaken, but even if $E$ was a vector space (pretty sure you meant to say bundle) we can't have $TE\cong E$ because the dimension of the tangent bundle to an $n$ dimensional manifold is $2n$.

Comment: @ChristopherQuinnLaFondJr. Thank you for your comment, you are of course right. I think I corrected it now, although I am not sure whether or not $T_x E = T_x E_x$ is actually correct. Morally (thinking about the case where $E$ is the tangent bundle of $M$), I think this is right, but I don't know how to prove it.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! <> Two vector bundles with isomorphic fibers need not be isomorphic; we must analyze how the fibers over different trivializing sets are glued, or the equivalent. For instance, it would suffice to find subbundles of $TE$ isomorphic to $TM$ and to $E$ and compatible with your fiberwise decomposition.

Comment: What is the equation $E=s(M)\oplus E$ supposed to mean? $s(M)$ is not a vector bundle; it's a manifold.

Comment: @TedShifrin But $s: M \rightarrow E$, so $s(M)\subset E$ is a sub-vector bundle of $E$

Comment: When you take the direct sum of two vector bundles (let's forget about the $0$-vector bundle for a moment) $E$ and $F$, then it is not the case that $T(E\oplus F) \cong TE\oplus TF$. Just look at dimensions. You have two copies of the tangent bundle of the base there.

Answer (score 0):

Come to think of it, the above way seems more complicated than I initially thought. I came up with a better way to prove $T_xE = T_x M \oplus E_x$ that also makes clear why we have this particular splitting:

If we denote by $\pi : E \rightarrow M$ the bundle map, i.e. $v \in E_x \mapsto x\in M$, then we can use the differential $d\pi : TE \rightarrow TM$:

$$\ker d\pi(x) = \{ v \in T_{x} E \,\vert\, \exists \gamma \in C^1((-\varepsilon,\varepsilon), E) : \gamma(0) = x, \dot{\gamma}(0) = v, \text{ and }\frac{d}{d t} \pi (\gamma(t)) \vert_{t=0} = 0\}$$

This means $\pi(\gamma(t))$ is constant, so $\gamma(t) \in E_x$ for all $t\in(-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$, which is equivalent to $v = \dot{\gamma}(0) \in T_x E_x$, so we get $\ker d\pi(x) = T_xE_x \cong E_x$.

On the other hand, since $d\pi$ is surjective (b.c. of $M\hookrightarrow E$), and since it is also linear, it induces the bijection
$$T_xE/T_xE_x\cong T_x M$$
and hence we get the desired formula.

**EDIT**

I forgot to check that $T_xE_x\cap ds(T_xM) = \{0\}$. This follows because $s$ is the zero-section: If $v\in T_x E_x \cap ds(T_xM)$, there exists a curve $\gamma(t) \in M\, \forall t\in (-\varepsilon,\varepsilon)$ with $v = \frac{d}{dt} s(\gamma(t)) \vert_{t=0}$, but $s(\gamma(t)) \in E_x$ is constantly $0_x \in E_x$, so $v = 0$.

Maybe all this has been obvious from the start, but I'm kinda new to differential topology, so please excuse my initial question.

Comment: Not quite. You can have $V/W \cong U$ without having $V\cong W\oplus U$. Where are you using the fact that you have the zero section rather than an arbitrary section?

Comment: @TedShifrin Oh I see. But since the first part should be correct, couldn't I just write $T_xE  = T_xE_x\oplus (T_x E_x)^\perp$ (since $T_x E$ is a finite dimensional vector space) and then show with my second argument that the orthogonal complement is isomorphic to $T_x M$? Thank you btw for all your helpfull comments!

Comment: So you're putting a metric on the bundle. This is additional structure and is a significant assumption. For example, your argument would no longer work in the holomorphic category.

Comment: @TedShifrin You're right, I forgot about that ^^ So what about this: We use the differential of the zero-section $d s(x) : T_xM \rightarrow T_xE$. Then $d\pi (ds (T_x M)) = d(\pi \circ s)(T_x M) = T_x M$, so we get that $ds (T_xM)$ is at least not in the kernel of $d\pi$. But how does one get surjectivity now? I mean, how can we prove that $ds (T_x M )$ is actually everything that is missing?

Comment: Again, where are you using the fact that $s$ is the zero section? $\pi\circ s = \text{id}_M$ holds for every section. It *is* the case that the image of $ds_x$ and $E_x$ span $T_{s(x)}E$ for every section $s$. So what is special/canonical about the zero section?

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm sorry for not getting the point :-|. All I see is that $s$ being the zero-section (i.e. $s(x)=0_x \in E_x \forall x∈M$) tells us that no non-zero vector from $T_x E_x$ can lie in $ds(TxM)$, so $\text{Im}( ds(x)) \cap T_x E_x = \{0\}$, meaning it is at least part of the complement in the direct sum.

Comment: Again, what you're saying has nothing to do with the zero section; it's true for any section. The issue is that the zero section is the only one that is "natural" and doesn't depend on arbitrary choices.

Comment: @TedShifrin I can understand what you mean, but I don't really see where I make arbitrary choices. Could you please give me a hint where exactly the problems arise if I pick another section than the zero section?

Comment: You choose a section, and this is quite arbitrary. Then you only get a splitting along that section. This is not a natural construction. How does anyone else make the same choice?